# App with Initial time-limited subscription then Auto-Renewable

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have an app that I plan to introduce soon, but I still have a couple of questions even after reading everything I could find.  Maybe I'm just missing the obvious.  The App requires a service subscription, because of the server monitoring and analysis required in the background.

I'd like the original App purchase to include a one year subscription to the service and then allow the user to renew (preferably I'd like to use the auto-renew option) towards the end of that period.

Can I just note the in the iTunes Store App description that the purchase includes a one year subscription, then prompt with a renewal notice after that period?

I've seen some comments about offering the App for free with limited usability, then doing an In-App Purchase, but I'd like to avoid having customers downloading the app, going through the initialization steps, but then not subscribing.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: How will you deal with (ab)users taking advantage of the initial "free" period and using it indefinitely? This is a problem that is keeping me from implementing a similar mechanism for one of my own apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I just note the in the iTunes Store App description that the purchase includes a one year subscription, then prompt with a renewal notice after that period?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks Alan!  Do you know if Apple will accept the App now, without all of the In App purchase code in place, but with the intention of doing an upgrade well before the end of the year?

Comment: Yeah they will, but they'll review the 'subscription model' you've chosen anew, so there's no guarantee they'll approve the changes then.